# Split single rows into multiple rows using a cell for conditional formatting in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rows

How do I get multiple lines with all the other column values as same but the PO number line split into singular values.
I would like to get a dataframe back that I can use to generate a new excel files that has multiple rows for each PO number.
[image: This Is my data]
[image: This is how I want it]

| Workflow ID | PO Number |
| --- | --- |
| 260019 | 21274 / 21081 / 21082 / 21083 / 21084 / 21085 / 21 |

Comment: From first file is generated DataFrame?

Comment: Yes the first file is my source file and I take the whole thing into a data frame called X and I want to rewrite all the lines in X with multiple PO numbers as the second picture.

Comment: Super,after convert file to  DataFrame what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? Or better is share  excel file with only first header row by gdocs, dropbox or similar.

Comment: can you post the output of `df.head(3).to_dict()` as code? so that we can reproduce your 1st dataframe –

Comment: Can you please show me how ? I will share the excel file with you